# Lazy JSON encoding

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

Consider the following:

```
z = [{"x" => 5}, 2, 3].lazy.map{ |i| i}
#=> #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator::Lazy: [{"x"=>5}, 2, 3]>:map>
z.first
#=> {"x"=>5}
```

When I try to convert `z` into JSON, I get the following unexpected result:

```
z.to_json
#=> "\"#<Enumerator::Lazy:0x00000001cb0448>\""
```

Why isn't `to_json` enumerating this lazy enumerator?

Comment: `to_json` should be requesting what?

Comment: Each item in the collection.

Comment: No, it does not request each item.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was wrong. Lazy is irrelevant (except for the fact that it internally converts the receiver to an enumerator). The real answer is: because `z` is an enumerator.

Comment: Perhaps due to possible issues with stuff like `(1..Float::INFINITY)`, but I agree I would have expected `to_json` to just iterate it all. You can force it with `to_a.to_json` instead of just `.to_json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great blog post here detailing how to do lazy json encoding. It requires monkey patching, so it's not ideal, but it succinctly covers the topic:

http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/03/13/optimizing-rails-for-memory-usage-part-4-lazy-json-generation-and-final-thoughts/

Code to monkey-patch:

https://gist.github.com/brianhempel/56823fb777fb567b676a

Answer (score 2):

`to_json` does not process enumerators. It only dumps its string notation:

```
> [].to_enum.to_json
=> "\"#<Enumerator:0x00000002503190>\""
```

You need to convert your enumerator to an array first:

```
> z.to_a.to_json
=> "[{\"x\":5},2,3]"
```

To clarify further, the array has its own generator module:

```
> [].method(:to_json).owner
=> JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Array
```

Whereas the enumerator only has the default:

```
> [].to_enum.method(:to_json).owner
=> JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object
```

Comment: `to_a` works, but is what I was trying to avoid. Consider a streaming JSON encoder: https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby. I wanted to avoid have the entire array in memory and progressively encode the json while stream the result over a socket.

Comment: Unfortunately `yajl` has the same behaviour of dumping an Enumerator's string notation.

Comment: Even in Rails' ActiveSupport, an enumerator (enumerable) is converted to an array first. See [active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb) and [active_support/json/encoding.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb). You could have used `require 'active_support'; ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(enumerator)`.

Answer (score 0):

To those who seek a way to write a **huge** object into a **json file** but crash with `to_json`, use this instead:
`JSON.dump(arr_or_hash, File.open('my.json', 'w'))`

and if you just want the json string:
`JSON.generate(arr_or_hash)`